# Extract three groups: between second and second to last, between second to last and last, and after last underscores

Tags: r, regex

can someone help with these regular expressions?

```
d_total_v_conf.int.low_all
```

I want three expressions: `total_v`, `conf.int.low`, `all`

I can't just capture elements before the third `_`, it is more complex than that:

```
d_share_v_hskill_wc_mean_plus
```

Should yield `share_v_hskill_wc`, `mean` and `plus`

The first match is for all characters between the second and the penultimate `_`, the second match takes all between the penultimate and the last `_` and the third takes everything after the last `_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sub` to capture the groups and create a delimiter, to `scan`

```
f1 <- function(str_input) {
     scan(text = sub("^[^_]+_(.*)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)$",
       "\\1,\\2,\\3", str_input), what = "", sep=",")
 }
f1(str1)
#[1] "total_v"      "conf.int.low" "all" 

f1(str2)
#[1] "share_v_hskill_wc" "mean"              "plus"
```

---

If it is a `data.frame` column

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   extract(col1, into = c('col1', 'col2', 'col3'), 
            "^[^_]+_(.*)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)$")
#               col1         col2 col3
#1           total_v conf.int.low  all
#2 share_v_hskill_wc         mean plus
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "d_total_v_conf.int.low_all"  
str2 <- "d_share_v_hskill_wc_mean_plus" 
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(str1, str2))
```

Comment: Thanks! Does this work inside ```separate```? Inside the ```sep``` argument

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito this is based on capture groups, so you can use `extract` instead of `separate` i.e. `df1 %>% extract(col1, into = c('col1', 'col2', 'col3'), "^[^_]+_(.*)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)$")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a single regex that yields the three groups as requested:

```
(?<=^[^_]_)((?:(?:(?!_).)+)|_)+(_[^_]+$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mZQx5X/1/)

The idea is to use a lookaround, plus an explict match for the first group, an everything-but batch in the middle, and another explicit match for the last part.
You may need to adjust the start and end anchors if those strings show up in free text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *{unglue}* for this task :

```r
library(unglue)
x <- c("d_total_v_conf.int.low_all", "d_share_v_hskill_wc_mean_plus")
pattern <- "d_{a}_{b=[^_]+}_{c=[^_]+}"
unglue_data(x, pattern)
#>                   a            b    c
#> 1           total_v conf.int.low  all
#> 2 share_v_hskill_wc         mean plus
```

what you want basically is to extract a, b and c from a pattern looking like "d_{a}_{b}_{c}", but where b and c are made of one or more non underscore characters, which is what "[^_]+" means in regex.